# Stop sending GPS coordinates Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, gps

My google maps app is sending my coordinates every 5 seconds after I click the button (mapbttn). I want to make another button to stop sending these coordinates. How can I do that?

Here is my .java file:

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Button mapbttn;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mapbttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setRangeButton);

        mapbttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btncoord();
            }
        });

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + location.getLatitude() + '\n' + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                }, 10);
                return;
            } else {
                btncoord();
            }
        }
        Bundle save = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (save != null) color = save.getString("marker color");
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    btncoord();
                return;
        }
    }

    public void btncoord() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply un-register your location manager like

`locationManager.removeUpdates(ActivityName.this);`

[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Comment: NOTE:  you should also do this in your onDestroy of your activity otherwise it won't stop

Comment: My pleasure @AndreeaMateescu

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void stopUpdates(){
    locationManager.removeUpdates(context);
}
```

call `stopUpdate()` method on stop button.

Comment: why would you post an answer which is already here. there are lot other unanswered question you can try .be ethical

Comment: @PavneetSingh as you can see on SO one question have multiple answers. When I was writing the answer you won the race. And I elaborate answer as per author need.

Comment: you mean you don't wanna be ethical by taking other non-ethical examples, plus at-least give a valid argument to prove your side otherwise don't give. quite funny so much elaboration is there

Comment: @PavneetSingh I don't have enough knowledge to argue with you. As I compare my answer with your there is a difference your answer is activity specific it can be use only in Activity class mine is different I am passing context explicitly.

Comment: thanks buddy ,i don't like useless arguements either , all i would suggest is, SO also encourage edit as suggestion ,you should use it.

Comment: @PavneetSingh let author decide which is useful for him. :)

Comment: you mean still you don't want to use edit suggestions in future ,have some ethics buddy

Comment: @PavneetSingh I like to use edit. But in that case we both was in the race. There is only 2 mins different.

Comment: I've tried this: ` public void stopSending() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    } ` , but it's not working....